# Laravel 7 One To Many Relations?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Below are all of the models, migrations and controller.

**Donation Model**

```php
class Donation extends Model
{
    protected $guarded =[];

    public function users(){
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }

    public function items(){
        return $this->belongsTo(DonationItems::class);
    }
}
```

**Donation Items Model:**

```php
class DonationItems extends Model
{
    protected $guarded=[];

    public function donation(){
        return $this->hasMany(Donaition::class);
    }
}
```

**Donation Items Migration:**

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('donation_items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('category');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Donation Migration:**

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('donations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('item');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('donation_item_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

In my controller I want to access the items as follows:

```php
$don = Donation::all();
$don->items;
```

But I'm unable to achieve this.

Comment: Is this your requirement: Donation has many Items, an Item belongs to a Donation?  Also you have a type here: return $this->hasMany(`Donaition`::class) you have an extra `i`

Comment: @user3532758 yes I've found the typo, and I want to know that a user has donated something so which category item belongs to either it is a food medical service kind of that.

Comment: Why not give eager loading a try. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading. Try `Donation::with('items')->get()`

Also, `donation` relationship in DontationItems class should be a `belogsTo` relationship.

Comment: You have a typo mistake and you need to call like this `$don = Donation::find(1);
$don->items;`

Comment: @user3532758 tried eager loading `{{$donnor->categories->category}}' but when i do this in my view it doesn't give me my required field it shows this error
**Property [category] does not exist on this collection instance.**

Comment: @user3532758 I'm trying to create an admin panel so the admin will know all the donations. I think we don't need find here?.

Comment: [{"id":1,"category":"shop","donaition_id":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{"id":2,"category":"food","donaition_id":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}]

I get this by eager loading but when i try to get any field from the related table say 
`$donor->items->id`
It shows an error `Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Answer (score 0):

Its not working because laravel follows one rule for relationships:

> Remember, Eloquent will automatically determine the proper foreign key column on the Comment model. By convention, Eloquent will take the "snake case" name of the owning model and suffix it with _id. So, for this example, Eloquent will assume the foreign key on the Comment model is post_id.

So you can try by supplying local and foreign id

**So it would look something like this**

**Donation Model**
class Donation extends Model
{
protected $guarded =[];

```
    public function users(){
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }

    public function items(){
        return $this->belongsTo(DonationItems::class, 'donation_item_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

**Donation Items Model:**

```
class DonationItems extends Model
{
    protected $guarded=[];

    public function donation(){
        return $this->hasMany(DonationItems::class, 'id', 'donation_item_id');
    }
}
```

I am writing from my head you might need to swap local and foreign ID's

Comment: **It gives that error when do by your method

`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'donation_items.donation_item_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `donation_items` where `donation_items`.`donation_item_id` = 1 and `donation_items`.`donation_item_id` is not null)`

Comment: In dontation items model, relationship needs to be `$this->hasMany(Donaition::class, 'id', 'donation_item_id');`

Comment: @WaheedSindhani Why don't you try following the documentation examples as practice? Documentation is pretty good.

Comment: Then just change `(DonationItems::class, 'donation_item_id', 'id');` into `(DonationItems::class, 'id', 'donation_item_id);`